# Using gganimate and getting all kind of errors

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to create an animation using [`gganimate`](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/gganimate-how-to-create-plots-with-beautiful-animation-in-r/):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(gifski)
library(gganimate)

load("covid-19-es.Rda")
casos <- ggplot(data,aes(x=Fecha))+geom_point(aes(y=casos,color="Casos"))+geom_point(aes(y=salidas,color="Salidas"))+theme_tufte()+transition_states(Fecha,transition_length=2,state_length=1)+labs(title='Day: {frame_time}')
animate(casos, duration = 5, fps = 20, width =800, height = 600, renderer=gifski_renderer())
anim_save("casos.png")
```

The data file used is [here](https://github.com/JJ/covid-reports/blob/master/covid-19-es.Rda).

Initially I used geom_lines instead of geom_point, but that produced an error saying:

```
Error in seq.default(range[1], range[2], length.out = nframes) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
```

and

```
Error in transform_path(all_frames, next_state, ease, params$transition_length[i],  : 
  transformr is required to tween paths and lines
```

Either it does not like lines, or does not like couples of them. Switched to point, and followed advice in gganimate issues to create a file. However, that produces different kind of errors:

```
Error: Provided file does not exist
```

which I really can't figure out, since I simply didn't provide any file. Trying to save anyway produces

```
Error: The animation object does not specify a save_animation method
```

So I don't really know if I'm doing something wrong, using a deprecated version (or package) or what.

Versions used

- R 3.6
- ggplot 2_3.3.0
- gganimate 1.0.5
- gifski 0.8.6

Comment: Curious about what you want to animation to look like, since you have the date on the x-axis and are using it as a faceting variable. Do you want to line revealed over time? In which case you might want `transition_reveal()`

Comment: @paqmo yes, that was my intention...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be the use of `{frame_time}`.

If you're calling `transition_states`, use `{closest_state}` for your state tracking. Alternatively, call `transition_time` and use `{frame_time}`.

This works for me, using `transition_states` and `{closest_state}`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gifski)
library(gganimate)

load("covid-19-es.Rda")

my_plot <- ggplot(data,aes(x = Fecha)) + 
    geom_point(aes( y =casos, color = "Casos")) +
    geom_point(aes(y = salidas, color = "Salidas")) +
    transition_states(Fecha, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
    labs(title = 'Day: {closest_state}')

animate(
    plot = my_plot,
    render = gifski_renderer(),
    height = 600,
    width = 800, 
    duration = 5,
    fps = 20)

anim_save('my_gif.gif')
```

Alternatively (and this is a bit smoother):

```
my_plot <- ggplot(data,aes(x = Fecha)) + 
    geom_point(aes( y =casos, color = "Casos")) +
    geom_point(aes(y = salidas, color = "Salidas")) +
    transition_time(Fecha) +
    labs(title = 'Day: {frame_time}')
```

- I've removed the `theme` call because it's not relevant
- I've saved as a gif instead of png
- The package versions I'm using are as follows:

```
> packageVersion('ggplot2')
[1] ‘3.3.0’
> packageVersion('gifski')
[1] ‘0.8.6’
> packageVersion('gganimate')
[1] ‘1.0.5’
```

- I'm using R-3.6.3.

[image: gif]

Comment: That works. However, only difference seems to be the theme. Is that the case?

Comment: The theme doesn't matter; I've just edited the post with some more info about the issue, hope that helps.