# "Error: Provided file does not exist" when using gganimate with lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820794/using-gganimate-and-getting-all-kind-of-errors/60821350#60821350), I tried, as suggested by [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820794/using-gganimate-and-getting-all-kind-of-errors/60821350#comment107609418_60820794), to use `geom_line` and `transition_reveal`. Since using several `geom_line` statements seemed to clash with gganimate (giving warnings about using a single element in a group and not rendering anything) I tried to gather everything into a single column and a single ggplot2 statement, here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(transformr)
library(gifski)
library(gganimate)
library(tidyr)

load("covid-19-es.Rda")
data <- gather(data,Tipo,Cuantos,c(casos,salidas))
my_plot <- ggplot(data,aes(x = Fecha, y = Cuantos, group= Tipo, color=Tipo)) + 
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(Fecha) + ease_aes("linear")+
  labs(title='Day: {closest_state}')

animate(
  plot = my_plot,
  render = gifski_renderer(),
  height = 600,
  width = 800, 
  duration = 10,
  fps = 20)

anim_save('gifs/casos-salidas-linea.gif')
```

The data file used is [here](https://github.com/JJ/covid-reports/blob/master/covid-19-es.Rda). I'm getting lots of warning when using animate, but it's finally killed with the unhelpful message (again):

```
Error: Provided file does not exist
```

At the end of the day, what I need is to animate line charts with `ggplot2`. If there's any other method, it'll be very wellcome

Versions used

- R 3.6
- ggplot 2_3.3.0
- gganimate 1.0.5
- gifski 0.8.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The labeling variable you want is `{frame_along}`, so: `labs(title='Day: {frame_along}')`. It is not super clear from the reference manual right now (nor the error messages), but including an unfamiliar label variable seems to prompt these errors. `{closest_state}` goes with `transition_states()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

load("covid-19-es.Rda")

data <- gather(data,Tipo,Cuantos,c(casos,salidas))

ggplot(data,aes(x = Fecha, y = Cuantos, color=Tipo)) + 
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(Fecha) + 
  ease_aes("linear") +
  labs(title='Day: {frame_along}')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>